# Does the "out" stage of the aggregation pipeline keeps an ordered collection?

Tags: mongodb

After sorting my collection I want to store it using the "out" stage of the aggregation pipeline. Does this stage ensures that the order of the documents is the same as the one produced by the "sort" stage?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `$out` sends documents to storage engine, then there could be a shift in order connected with document/bson object size, as MMAP storage engine uses padding to allow natural document growth.

removing $out from aggregate and adding this snippet will display documents size (you could add any other field to get more diagnostic data).
When we will have a situation that documents fits in a gap between two other documents, then it will be added there - so order will be changed-> that means $out will preserver order, but storage engine can add a noise to that.

```
db.coll.aggregate([pipeline]).forEach(function(doc)
{
    print(" _id: "+ doc._id + "\t\t size: " + Object.bsonsize(doc)  )          
})
```

### Solution

after a chat - and recommendation to switch from MMAP to WT -query was ran with success!

Comment: So there isn't any way to preserve the sort order? I work with a large dataset and the sort operation requires an important amount of time, therefore the pre-computation .... Thank you very much

Comment: @A.M. could you provide monog version and storage engine used?

Comment: mongo db version v3.2.6 and the "db.serverStatus().storageEngine" returns { "name" : "mmapv1", "supportsCommittedReads" : false, "persistent" : true }